# A possible variation of diagonally dominant matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

The following is a classical result:

> Let $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, $n\ge 2$. If $|a_{ii}|>\sum_{j\neq i}|a_{ij}|$ for all $1\le i\le n$, then $|A|\neq 0$.

It can be proved via establishing the linear independence of the column vectors of $A$. Such matrices are called *diagonally dominant matrix* and are widely used in numerical methods.

I wonder if we can “loosen” the condition a little bit, which might make it more convenient for us to use it.

> Let $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, $n\ge 3$. If $|a_{ii}a_{jj}|>\left(\sum_{k\neq i}|a_{ik}|\right)\left(\sum_{l\neq j}|a_{jl}|\right)$ for any $1\le i\neq j\le n$, then $|A|\neq 0$.

Is the statement above correct? I have tried to calculate several examples and have not got any counterexamples. So I wonder if there is any rigorous proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if $n=2$ the statement is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $Ax=0$ with $x\neq 0$.

(1) If $x$ has only $1$ non-zero entry, say $x_1\neq 0$ and $x_i=0$ for $i\neq 1$, then $a_{11}=0$.

(2) Assum $x$ has at least $2$ non-zero entry. We may assume $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the largest two in absolute value, that is $|x_1|,|x_2|\geq \max_{j\neq 1,2} |x_j|$.

$$|a_{11}x_1|=|\sum_{j\neq 1}a_{1j}x_j|\leq \sum_{j\neq 1}|a_{1j}|\cdot|x_2|,$$
$$|a_{22}x_2|=|\sum_{k\neq 2}a_{2k}x_j|\leq \sum_{k\neq 2}|a_{2k}|\cdot|x_1|,$$
that is
$$|a_{11}|\leq \sum_{j\neq 1}|a_{1j}|\cdot\frac{|x_2|}{|x_1|},$$
$$|a_{22}|\leq \sum_{k\neq 2}|a_{2k}|\cdot\frac{|x_1|}{|x_2|}.$$
It follows that
$$|a_{11}|\cdot|a_{22}|\leq (\sum_{j\neq 1}|a_{1j}|)\cdot(\sum_{k\neq 2}|a_{2k}|).$$